# Sending all of argv through sockets

Tags: c++, sockets

Just wondering if there is an easy way to send all of argv.

client.cpp

```
for(int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
     send(sock, argv[i], strlen(argv[i], 0);
cout << "\nMessage Sent\n";
```

Client Output

```
./main 1 send this to server
```

server.cpp

```
valread = read(new socket, buffer, 1024);
cout << buffer;
cout << "\nMessage Received\n";
```

Server Output

```
./main
Awaiting Connection
send
Message Received
Awaiting Connection
```

This is what I had in mind, but the server only ever recieves the first argv. For the socket programming, I am mostly referencing gfg.

Comment: Did you try calling `read` multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are wrong: you call `send` X times but only `read` once. This will only work if a number of circumstances align in your favor.

An obvious solution is to construct a single message from `argv` and send that in one message, but then you still need to solve two problems:

- the formatting problem: how do you convert a `char*[]` to a message? I chose to separate each by a NUL byte.
- the framing problem: how does the server know that a message has ended? A common approach is to prefix every message with the number of bytes in that message.

So, on the client side:

```
std::stringstream ss;
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
     if (i > 1) ss << "\0";
     ss << argv[i];
}
auto message = ss.str();
uint32_t len = htole32(message.length()); // explicitly format the length as little-endian
send(sock, &len, sizeof(len), 0);
send(sock, message.c_str(), message.length(), 0);
```

On the server side:

```
uint32_t len;
read(sock, &len, sizeof(len);
len = le32toh(len);

std::string buf;
buf.reserve(len);
read(sock, buf.data(), len);
// finally, extract each NUL-terminated word.
```